# How to get the uid of a registered user with ionic and firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm trying to register a user with firebase, once the user is registered, I would like to add them to the firestore database but I can't access the uid of the user that just registered.

```
registerUser(name: string, email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((newUser:any) => {
    console.log(newUser.uid)
});
}
```

newUser.uid is undefined, how do I access this value?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the documentation here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword

the function returns "returns firebase.Promise containing non-null [firebase.auth.UserCredential](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.UserCredential)"

```
console.log(newUser.user.uid)
```